# Is it possible to apply css transform to image on currently transformed div

Tags: css, webkit, transform, css-animations

I have a div which is already rotated, however all content within it is transformed in the same fashion.

I have plugged a fiddle below to better illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

What would be the proper way to transform the image of the 'moon' so that it maintains it's original shape as it travels the path?

Comment: Any one? Por favor? :[

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to transform the image is applying the oposite transforms that you have applied to all the elements.

In your case, that includes the rotateX and rotateY in the path, and the rotate in the animation.

for this to work ok, you also need to specify  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; so that the transformations can really undo the previous transforms.

There is a problem, though, and I think this is a Chrome bug: when you apply a keyframes animation, preserve-3d stops working.

So, sorry to say, I am unable to make it work; and I think that it is not posible if this bug isn't corrected. May be in another browser ?

you can check the static correct fiddle [correct fiddle without animation](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/xDv6v/1/)

You can see there also the inverse keyframes animation, that you would need to make it work.

I would suggest you to create the elipse scaling the circle in the plane, instead of rotating it in 3D, I believe you can make that work this way

The CSS end like that:

```
#Path{margin:5% 15% auto; position:relative;
       height:500px;width:500px;
       background-color:rgba(0,200,200, .1);
       border:1px solid black;
       border-radius:300px;
       -webkit-transform:perspective(0px) rotateX(50deg) rotateY(25deg);
       -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;}

#moonContain {width:500px;height:500px;position:absolute; margin-left:-0.5%;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            }

#moon { width:150px;-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -webkit-transform:perspective(0px)  rotateX(-50deg) rotateY(-25deg);    }


@-webkit-keyframes Rotate        
{from {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
 to   {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}}    
@-webkit-keyframes counterRotate        
{from {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
 to   {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}}
```

**Correction**

I wrongly interpret the problem that arises when you set the animation in the moon itself; and I thought it was a bug in Chrome. What it really was happening was that the animation was animating the transform property, and that undoes the transform property specified in the moon itself.
Correct answer:

set both transforms in the animation, even though the later is constant:

```
@-webkit-keyframes counterRotate        
{from {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg) rotateX(-50deg) rotateY(-25deg);}
 to   {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) rotateX(-50deg) rotateY(-25deg);}}    

 #moon { width:150px;-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-animation:counterRotate 15s linear infinite;}
```

### [Correct demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/xDv6v/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Make the moon rotate in the opposite direction!

http://jsfiddle.net/hsntY/3/

```
#moon { width:150px; animation:RotateRev 15s linear infinite;}

@keyframes RotateRev        
    {from {transform:rotate(360deg);}
     to   {transform:rotate(0deg);}}
```

(also, I can understand if it was just for example or something, but you should use the standard spec AND have prefix fallbacks)